# V-For from "Computed" doesn't show up

Tags: vuejs2, computed-properties, v-for

I am using a v-for inside a template to show a list from a computed property. But even though it works when i refresh, i cannot see the listed items when i firstly get on the page. If i v-for my contacts, i cannot filter.

So my data and computed methods look like this:

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
       contacts: this.$store.getters.loadedContacts,
       search: ""
      };
    },
computed: {
  filterContacts(contacts) {
    return this.contacts.filter(contact => {
      return contact.name.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase());
    });
  }   
};
```

And i call it in my HTML like this (filterContacts):

```
<v-list two-line v-if="contacts">
  <template v-for="(contact, index) in filterContacts">

  <v-list-tile-content>
      <v-list-tile-title>{{ contact.name }}</v-list-tile-title>
        <v-list-tile-action-text>{{ contact.position }}</v-list-tile-action-text>
  </v-list-tile-content>  

  </template>
</v-list>
```

So the actual question is this: Why do need to refresh my page to see the results from the for loop ?
If i don't call the filterContacs, i cannot use my filter.

Any suggestions how to solve both filtering and v-for loop?

Thanks and sorry if this is a novice one!
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Try replacing `this.contacts.filter` with `this.$store.getters.loadedContacts`.

Comment: Also, you can add dummy data in various places to see where this is falling down.

Answer (score 1):

Data of the component is set upon creation. The getter in the store probably doesn't return any data yet.

You can safely replace `this.contacts` in your computed with `this.$store.getters.loadedContacts`.

Other thing you can choose for, perhaps more elegant, is to use vuex's `mapGetter` helper. It reactively maps a vuex getter to your component's computed property (read more here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper).

With mapGetters you would:

```
...mapGetters({
  contacts: 'loadedContacts'
})
```

And then just remove contacts from your data declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I actually observed at what you said. Indeed by replacing `this.contacts` with `this.$store.getters.loadedContacts` did fixed my problem. I removed also "contacts" from data().

Thanks!